# Does an unordered list make sense in a math paper, if the author defines it to be unordered?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

I'm reading a paper which the author describes lists of numbers $(\alpha,\beta, \gamma, ... )$ that he will study, but he says to let these lists be unordered and the numbers not necessarily distinct.

The "not necessarily distinct" part of it is fine, as lists allow for repeats, but unordered lists seem ... not rigorous.

Is this ok for the author to do?  It's an old paper, published a couple of decades ago.

Similarly, there is some discussion about *sets* of numbers that allow for repeats - this again seems unusual, since I know sets to be objects that contain *distinct* numbers, e.g., the spectrum of a matrix is the set of *distinct* eigenvalues of the matrix.

Is all of this fine, so long as the author *defines* it to be that way?

Thanks,

Comment: Please give the reference. If "a couple of decades ago" means it was published around 1996, then it isn't a very old paper.

Comment: I don't see a difference between an unordered list that allows repetitions and a set that allows repetitions.  Either one is usually called a multiset (in mathematics) or a bag (in computer science).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly OK as long as he makes clear what he means - as he seems to have.

Nowadays in combinatorics he might call it a *multiset* - but he might want to explain what that means ...

Comment: Where "nowadays" means since the late 1970s. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset.